# How can I schedule Focus Mode on my Android phone?

Tags: digital-wellbeing

Google have launched Digital Wellbeing features in newer Android versions, including Focus Mode. Focus Mode lets you select a list of allowed apps and block all others, during periods when you want to focus and avoid distractions.

According to [this blog post by Google](https://blog.google/products/android/android-focus-mode/), it is possible to schedule Focus Mode:

> Their feedback inspired us to include a few new features with today’s launch. For example, we’ve added an option to automatically turn Focus mode on and off for the days and times that you choose (e.g. from 9 a.m. to 5 p.m. on weekdays). This is especially handy for setting daily schedules; you can minimize distractions during the hours you’re at work, school or home.

My phone has Focus Mode, but it does not seem to have a way to schedule Focus Mode. How is Focus Mode scheduled on phones where this is supported?

Comment: @beeshyams The link doesn't instructions on scheduling. I'm interested in the answer for any Android phone, because I want to know what it looks like on phones where Digital Wellbeing is fully supported.

Answer (score 1):

On one plus 7 Android 10,you can schedule this way: Digital Wellbeing &  Parental control → Tap on Focus mode → on next screen select distracting apps → Set a schedule → Set schedule (set days of week and time) → turn on now. From 3 buttons menu you can also add a quick settings shortcut.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)